# Xamarin Android: Scrolling auto-sizing text in ListView make text size decrease

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, autosize

I have a custom label renderer to autosize text into single line according to the length of text. 
The auto-sizing is working fine but the issues is when I scroll multiple times in listview, the text will be getting smaller.

I found that this issues only happened when it's a long list (more than 25 items) and each item label is different length of text. If long list with same text length for each item label, scrolling autosizing text wouldn't make text size decrease.

I wonder if anyone could give me some advice. Many Thanks.

**Custom Label Renderer for autosizing text:**

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
 namespace WhiteLabel.Mobile.App.Droid.Renderers
 {
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
       public CustomLabelRenderer(Android.Content.Context ctx) : base(ctx)
       {

       }

       protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
          base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

          if (Control != null)
          {
             TextViewCompat.SetAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(Control, 15, 50, 1, TypedValue.DensityDefault);
             Control.SetLines(1);
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

**XAML code:**

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Asset}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
    SeparatorColor="Transparent"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    Footer="">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- Some Label Here -->
                <!-- ...... -->

                <customControls:CustomLabel  
                       Text="{Binding Price}"
                       Grid.Row="1" 
                       Grid.Column="1"  
                       HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />

                <!-- Some Label Here -->
                <!-- ...... -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: It works fine on my side , so you could better share your sample which contains the issue so that I can test it .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT, this is the sample with issues. I just realize if the item label in ListView are same length of text, text size wouldn't decrease while scrolling. I found that this issues only happened if the List is long (more than 25 items) and each item label is with different length of text.

Comment: I didn't see any link .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, did you able to see any issues if is long listview with different text length ?

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem .